# Como direcionar uma Action para uma view dentro de uma pasta?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

No meu Controller UGController tenho uma Action de nome Cadastro que me leva até a View Cadastro.cshtml que está na pasta UG.

Ou seja:

> ```
> Controller: UGController
> Action: Cadastro()
> Link: /UG/Cadastro
> View: /UG/Cadastro.cshtml
> ```

Até ai normal. Mas gostaria de criar uma pasta dentro da View UG para colocar outro arquivo

> ```
> Controller: UGController
> Action: ?
> Link: /UG/PDF/Lista
> View: /UG/PDF/Lista.cshtml
> ```

Dúvida: Como fazer com que a Action me leve até o Lista.cshtml com o link que eu descrevi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
return View("caminho/para/sua/pasta/NomeDaView");
```

Por exemplo:

```
Controller: MyController
Action: MyAction
Link: MyController/MyAction
View: Views/MyController/PastaQualquer/MyAction


public ActionResult MyAction()
{
   return View("PastaQualquer/MyAction")
}
```

Se você não resolver no `return View("")`, terá que criar uma nova rota.

Answer (score 0):

Para o teu caso ficaria:

```
return View("UG/PDF/Lista");
```