# Retornar view que está em outro diretório

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Adicionei uma pasta dentro de outra pasta na pasta views, desta forma:

> Views/Cadastro/Perfil

Dentro da pasta perfil estão os arquivos **.cshtml**. Porém, quando tento acessar os arquivos **.cshtml** recebo um erro na aplicação, já tentei esta solução: [Como direcionar uma Action para uma view dentro de uma pasta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26168/como-direcionar-uma-action-para-uma-view-dentro-de-uma-pasta) e não consegui resolver, o AP fala no final, que tenho que criar rota, mas não consigo.

Meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult Perfil() 
{ 
    var perfils = db.Perfil.Where(p => p.Nome != "Administrador" && p.IDStatus == 1).ToList(); 
    return View("Perfil/"+perfils); 
}
```

Recebo o seguinte erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste a forma que você está fazendo em seu controller. Qual o erro que apresenta?

Comment: Não tem problema, no início é assim mesmo. Caso tenha algo a acrescentar, você sempre poderá editar a sua própria pergunta. Não utilize o campo de respostas para isso.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so], faça um [tour], para aprender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site para assim aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso, você não precisa alterar a rota para exibir sua view, basta retorná-la em sua action, desta forma:

```
public ActionResult Perfil() 
{ 
    var perfils = db.Perfil.Where(p => p.Nome != "Administrador" && p.IDStatus == 1).ToList(); 
    return View("Perfil/Perfil",perfils); 
}
```

Neste caso, como você quer apenas retornar a view, mas não alterar a rota, basta retornar a view **Perfil** que está dentro do da pasta **Perfil**.

Comment: Randrade desculpe mas acho que não fui claro o suficiente: O Meu controller vai chamar a action Perfil, mas está action está dentro de outra pasta com o nome perfil, desta forma:

Views/Cadastro/Perfil/Perfil.cshtml ou seja Perfil.cshtml é minha action.

Comment: ok posso sim, vou fazer agora